# How to sketch the following discrete-time signal?

Tags: discrete-signals, transform

How to sketch the following discrete-time signal: 
\begin{gather*}
x[(n-1)^2]
\end{gather*} 
for the signal given below:
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I give you some hints and then you can solve this homework.

- Your $x[n]$ has only $8$ nonzero values. Figuring out what happens to them (in an exhaustive way) is not difficult.
- Consider $(n-1)^2$ and change $n$ over $(-\infty, \infty)$. You can see that it is always non-negative. It means that we never can have $(n-1)^2=-1$. Hence the samples of $x[n]$ for $n=-3,-2,-1$ are never used. We can only have samples of $x[n]$ at $n=0,1,2,3$.
- Solve $(n-1)^2=0$, $(n-1)^2=1$,$(n-1)^2=2$, $(n-1)^2=3$. Only accept those results that lead to an integer $n$. Then you can see at what $n$ in $x[(n-1)^2]$ we have what value of $x[n]$. For instance, $(n-1)^2=\color{red}1\Rightarrow n=0,2$. It means in $x[(n-1)^2]$ the samples at $n=0$ and $n=2$ are equal to $x[\color{red}1]=1$.
- Except at the points mentioned above, the transformed signal would be zero.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations. I solved the equations and got n=1 for (n-1)^2=0 , n=0,2 for (n-1)^2=1. For the last two equations I get no integer values. Does that mean that my new signal has a value of 1 at points n=0,2 and a value of 0 at point n=1 (and for the other points)? @LaurentDuval

Comment: Almost correct. You only have three nonzero terms, but $x[0]$ is also equal to one. Not zero. So your transformed signal has only three nonzero samples equal to one at $n = 0,1,2$.

Answer (score 1):

The set of indices where $x$ is non-zero is $(-4,\ldots,3)$. You can rephrase the question as:

> which $n$ (possibly real) are such as $(n-1)^2$ is an integer taking values in $(-4,\ldots,3)$

In other words, which integers in $(-4,\ldots,3)$ are (non-negative) squares?

Here, this is quite simple, only $0$ and $1$ are perfect squares, attained when $n=1$ (for $0^2=0$) and  $n=0$ or $n=2$ (for $1^2=1$).

So if $y[n] =x\left[(n-1)^2\right]$:

- $y[0] =x[1] $,
- $y[1] =x[0] $,
- $y[2] =x[1] $.